# Python struct.unpack equivalent in C

Tags: python, c

What I have in python is a

> string lenght = 4

, that I can unpack to get some values.

**Is there an equivalent of this function on python, in C?**

Comment: [Yes, there is](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Comment: can you tell me what is it?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, you are asking the other way around.

Comment: Se the [isocpp FAQ, Serializaion](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-no-inherit-no-ptrs). The link points to the section which I think is most relevant to your case.

Comment: In C the string would be a sequence of characters followed by a zero. So declaring a variable with enough bytes should be enough (apart from encoding, since strings are an abstraction). Maybe I do not understand the problem correctly. Pleae explain further and provide examples

Answer (score 2):

In C, there is no concept of "packing" like this. Whenever you have a char buffer such as

```
char buf[128];
```

whether you treat it like a string or a complex data structure is up to you. The simplest way would be to define a `struct` and copy data back and forth from your array.

```
struct MyStruct{
  int data1;
  int data2;
};

char buf[sizeof(struct MyStruct)];
struct MyStruct myStruct;
myStruct.data1 = 1;
myStruct.data2 = 2;
memcpy(buf, &myStruct, sizeof(struct MyStruct));
```

Please note that there IS some packing/padding that MAY happen here. For example, if you have a `short` in your struct, the compiler MAY use 4 bytes anyway. This also fails when you have to use pointers, such as `char*` strings in the structure.

Comment: Also, endianess may matter.